# Using multiple XSL files, generates multiple SVG tags so page doesn't render as expected

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am generating XML files in my server side code and using XslCompiledTransform.Transform to transform them with an external XSL file.

An example of one of the XSL files is like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>
  <xsl:param name='x' />
  <xsl:param name='y' />
  <xsl:param name='channel_number' />
  <xsl:param name='sequence_colour' />
  <xsl:param name='sequence_stroke' />
  <xsl:template match='/Sensor'>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
      <g transform="translate({$x},{$y})" id="S{$channel_number}">
        <rect x="85" y="0" width="90" height="30" rx="10" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="{$sequence_colour}" stroke-width="{$sequence_stroke}" />
        <rect x="12" y="32" width="8" height="18" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <rect x="20" y="55" width="220" height="95" fill="#F5F5FF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <rect x="20" y="80" width="30" height="40" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <line x1="20" y1="100" x2="50" y2="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I do this on individual objects, it works perfectly.

The problem arises when I want to display two or more objects on the same page. Instead of them appearing next to each other, there is a whole screen height between objects.

A sample of the final markup is this:

```
<Root>
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <g transform="translate(170.5,40.5)" id="S1">
        <rect x="85" y="0" width="90" height="30" rx="10" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <rect x="12" y="32" width="8" height="18" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <rect x="20" y="55" width="220" height="95" fill="#F5F5FF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <rect x="20" y="80" width="30" height="40" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
        <line x1="20" y1="100" x2="50" y2="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="translate(570.5,40.5)" id="S2">
      <rect x="85.5" y="0.5" width="90" height="30" rx="10" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
      <rect x="12.5" y="32.5" width="8" height="18" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
      <line x1="0.5" y1="40.5" x2="20" y2="40.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
      <line x1="220.5" y1="110.5" x2="240" y2="110.5" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" />
      <text x="95.5" y="80.5" font-family="sans-serif" font-size="20px" font-weight="bold" fill="black">S</text>
      <circle cx="275.5" cy="110.5" r="15" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="#FFFFFF" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</Root>
```

The translates have the correct figures in them (170.5,40.5) and (570.5,40.5). The y values are the same, so I would expect the SVG drawings to appear along side each other, but this is not the case.

I think it is due to having multiple SVG tags, but I don't know how to overcome this as I am transforming from multiple XSL files.

EDIT: It's definitely having multiple SVG tags. I copied the source HTML, saved it to a file, edited the additional SVG tags, so it only had the top svg tag with one closing svg tag and it renders exactly as expected.

How can I change the way I create my HTML to only have one SVG tag?

Comment: Just to clear things up: Do you have *one* input document or do you apply the compiled transform to several separate input documents in a loop?

Comment: I generate the XML on the fly, each time I generate one object I use the transform file, and then add that as an element to an XDocument. But, I could modify my code to generate the entire XML first if that would help.

Comment: That would definitely help. XSLT is designed to process one input document (even though you perfectly *can* also pass the list of DOM nodes that you intend to process as a parameter, you still need an input document - so why not use that in the first place). I'll fix up a version of your XSLT that deals with that. Doing *one* transformation should also perform nicer in the long run.

Comment: Speaking of which, `channel_number`, `sequence_colour` and `sequence_stroke` should really be elements in your XML, not parameters to the processor. (Same for `x` and `y`, which should either be translated to individual `height`/`width` measures per sensor or, if those are fixed, be applied only once to the entire output.)

Comment: OK. Just as some extra info, I will be looking at having 87 separate transform files. Basically I'm trying to create a Visio flowchart type output. I have 87 different object types that need to be displayed in different ways. Is using XSL really the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: It's definitely not a bad choice. How easy it will be in the end depends on how you model your input. With sensibly crafted XML, transforming it into SVG with XSLT should be a breeze. Can you put up an example of the three or four different objects you want to render?

Comment: In theory you could use [`ObjectXPathNavigator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950764.aspx) to skip the step of creating intermediate XML that serves no purpose other than being fed to an XSLT processor. `XslCompiledTransform` accepts any class that implements `IXPathNaviagable`, so why not create one over your original object graph. I've never tried that but it sounds intriguing.

Comment: I have added a screendump of 4 typical objects. I have only created XSLT files for 2 of them at the moment. Thanks, I will have a look into ObjectXPathNavigator. An additional thought: if I were going to stick with XSL, would it be easier to create one large XSLT file for all 87 objects instead of 87 separate ones?

Comment: I think keeping them all in one XSLT file helps. Otherwise you would need to `<xsl:include>` the parts which every time is a separate "file system access + parsing" step. If you can put the defining characteristics of every object you want to render in an XML document it's easy to write an XSL template for each of them - possibly even re-using SVG code you share between different renderings. It looks as if the objects you render do not have that many different properties. One straight-forward way could be to choose distinct element names (`<FooSensor>`) and attach all properties as attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Tomalak. There's quite a bit of information there for me to look into. Unfortunately, I won't be able to look into this for a few days. If I get stuck I'll post a new question. Thanks again.

Comment: Feel free to ping me through the comments here.